# GateIn - Why can't custom portal see all skins?

Tags: configuration, skin, gatein

This is a rather specific question to GateIn, but I can't get help anywhere else.

GateIn has a Skin Service which detects deployed skins automatically.
This works fine for the default portal container, which correctly lists all available skins in the Choose Skin dialogue.

However, in other portals, such as the sample-portal or my own custom portal, only the default skin is listed. what do I have to do to get the skins displayed in all portals?

Thank you.